# Inserting Spatial\Geometry in EF5 with dotConnect 6.7 for PostgreSQL

Tags: entity-framework, postgresql, devart

I installed the latest dotConnect for PostgreSQL. Im trying to insert a record in the Postgres DB. I have a geometry column what gives me errors. Here is the code:

```
using (var context = new WKP_DBEntities())
 {
    var Location = DbGeometry.PointFromText(string.Format("POINT({0} {1})", 157873, 364282), 28992);

    var record = new monitoring_object()
    {
        geometry = Location,
        last_changed_by = "ssg",
    };

    context.monitoring_object.Add(record);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
       at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
       at ConsoleApplicationGEOdata.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\Stefan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplicationGEOdata\ConsoleApplicationGEOdata\Program.cs:line 38
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.Data.UpdateException
       HResult=-2146233087
       Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
       Source=System.Data.Entity
       StackTrace:
            at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
            at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager entityCache)
            at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
            at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
       InnerException: System.ArgumentException
            HResult=-2147024809
            Message=Cannot convert value
            Source=Devart.Data.PostgreSql
            StackTrace:
                 at Devart.Data.PostgreSql.af.a(Object A_0, Type A_1, Encoding A_2)
                 at Devart.Data.PostgreSql.af.a(String A_0, Encoding A_1, PgSqlType A_2, Object A_3, Int32 A_4, Boolean A_5)
                 at Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlCommand.a(String A_0, Encoding A_1, ArrayList A_2, Boolean A_3)
                 at Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlCommand.InternalExecute(CommandBehavior behavior, IDisposable stmt, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
                 at Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.InternalExecute(CommandBehavior behavior, IDisposable stmt, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, Boolean nonQuery)
                 at Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean nonQuery)
                 at Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
                 at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
                 at Devart.Data.PostgreSql.Entity.y.a(CommandBehavior A_0)
                 at Devart.Common.Entity.i.b(CommandBehavior A_0)
                 at Devart.Data.PostgreSql.Entity.y.b(CommandBehavior A_0)
                 at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
                 at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
                 at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
            InnerException:
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please tell me you don't really mean PostgreSQL 6.7 and that you've made a typo. `SELECT version();` and paste the output into your question please. (OK, you can't possibly mean 6.7 because there was never a PostgreSQL 6.7 release; maybe you mean DotConnect 6.7 for PostgreSQL?)

Comment: You seem to have cut off the most important part of the exception; that exception output is incomplete.

Comment: Sorry it is DotConnect 6.7 for PostgreSQL. Changed it. For the exception thats all there is: I did a "Copy exception detail to the Clipboard". The last InnerException is null.

Comment: OK. Check the PostgreSQL server error logs, see if there's any query error reported there or whether the error is higher in the stack. You might want to talk to the DotConnect folks if so.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works in our environment:
a) dotConnect for PostgreSQL v 6.7.287
b) SharpMap v1 RC3
c) Postgis 2.0
d) DDL:
CREATE TABLE monitoring_object
(
id serial NOT NULL,
geometry geometry,
last_changed_by character varying
);

Please [give us](http://www.devart.com/company/contactform.html) the following information:
1) the version of your SharpMap. Be aware that current release of dotConnect for PostgreSQL supports SharpMap 1.0 RC3 ( http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/releases/view/106717 ). The 1.0 Final version will be supported soon
2) the version of your Postgis. It should be of the 2.0 (or higher) version. You can check it by executing "select postgis_version()" in the database
3) the DDL script of your monitoring_object table
4) if possible [send us](http://www.devart.com/company/contactform.html) a small test project

The corresponding Devart documentation is available at http://blogs.devart.com/dotconnect/enhanced-entity-framework-spatials-support-for-oracle-mysql-and-postgresql.html .